# C# Extracting values from datagridview - strange outcome

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a strange outcome when I run this code - I have a datagridview with a basic stock list (name, onHand, Min) when the onHand drops below Min I want to have some kind of alert. The problem I am having is that I am giving the values to a messagebox so I can see what is happening and if I put the 'onHand' value in the top 'if' block it always comes out as zero but 'min' outputs the correct values. If I put the 'Min' value in the top 'if' block THAT comes out as zero and the 'onHand' shows the correct value. I have been trying toi fix it for a while now and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Currently I have 'min' in the top 'if' block and the messagebox always shows min as zero but gives 'onHand' the correct value.

The code:

```
 private void btnLows_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int onHand = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int counter;


        for (counter = 0; counter < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count);
               counter++)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["min"].Value
            != null)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["min"].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
                {
                   onHand = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["min"].Value.ToString());

                   if (dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["onHand"].Value != null)
                   {
                       if (dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["onHand"].Value.ToString().Length != 0)
                       {
                           onHand = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["onHand"].Value.ToString());

                           if (onHand < min)
                           {
                               MessageBox.Show(onHand.ToString(), min.ToString());
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               MessageBox.Show(onHand.ToString(), min.ToString());
                           }
                       }
                   }
                }

            }
```

Comment: woo, that's a lot of nesting you've got going on there. Rather than outputting the values to a message box as your form of debugging, can I suggest using the built in debugger and stepping through the code? It will really help you see what is actually going on at each step.

Comment: I know.. I am learning! Thanks, I will do that I was stepping through the code but the answer was so simple I just couldn't see it! :)

Comment: Learning is fun! The debugger is an incredible tool and will save you many frustrations. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line (inside the first nested if-statement within your for-loop):

```
onHand = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["min"].Value.ToString());
```

Should probably be:

```
min = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[counter].Cells["min"].Value.ToString());
```

Currently you never set `min` to anything else but 0 when you define it.

Comment: That's it! Haha I had to smile when I read your answer I knew it as soon as I saw it :) Thanks so much!

Comment: @user1327563: You're welcome. Also, I'm not sure how you're binding your data to your `DataGridView`, but if you did so with a collection of objects (e.g. `MyType` objects), you could cast the row's data bound element to your type and access its properties instead of parsing data out of the cells (e.g. `onHand = (dataGridView1.Rows[counter].DataBoundItem as MyType).onHand;`).